# How to convert types when reading data from Elasticsearch using elasticsearch-spark in SPARK

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-spark

When i try to read data from elasticsearch using the `esRDD("index")` function in elasticsearch-spark, i get the results in type `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, scala.collection.Map[String,AnyRef])]`. And when i check the values, they are all type `AnyRef`. However, i saw in on [ES site](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html), it says :

> elasticsearch-hadoop automatically converts Spark built-in types to Elasticsearch types (and back)

My dependencies are:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0"  
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0"  
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.1.0"  
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11" % "5.4.0"
```

Do I miss something? And how can i convert the types in a convenient way?

Comment: Why are you reading RDDs if you are using spark 2 with es 5.4 ?

Comment: @eliasah because in the official documents, it use rdd.... nvm, i know how to do now. Thx

Comment: If you have found the solution, please share the solution with others and accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found a solution. 
If you use `esRDD`, all types information are lost.
It is better if we use:

```
val df = sparkSession.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").option("es.read.field.as.array.include", "").load("index")
```

You can config es in `option`, if you have done it before, `option` can be ignored.

The data returend is in `DataFrame`, and the data types are preserved (converted to `sql.DataTypes`) in schema as long as the conversion is supported by `elasticsearch-spark`.

And now you can do whatever you want.